# Certificate Issues Connecting to Websocket

Tags: python, windows, websocket, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a python program that connects to an API using the websocket client that has always worked fine but has not been connecting this morning on my windows 10 PC. I am aware of the DST Root CA X3 certificate expiration today and was having some issues connecting to a few websites from urllib, but I have since deleted the expired certificates from the "Intermediate Certificate" store and disabled DST Root CA X3 in the trusted store. By doing this, the issues visiting sites from urllib were resolved but the websocket API one persists. The certificate this API uses is a Globalsign Root CA R1 and the weird part is that I can reach the API just fine from my chrome browser and from piesocket.com/websocket-tester# but not my local PC using the python websocket client. I am lost here and was wondering if anyone knows anything about what the issue could be and how I can solve it?

Comment: I have a similar issue and also posted a question. Mine is Safari only, the websocket works ok in Firefox.  How's yours on Safari ?

Comment: Sorry I haven’t checked Safari , the issue arose on internet explorer/Microsoft edge and chrome for me and that’s what I’ve been focused on solving currently @blissweb

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this @mattwatkins? I believe I am experiencing a similar issue

Comment: @Apples292 If I remember correctly I believe I had to delete the expired certificate and replace it with a newly released one. I just followed a YouTube tutorial on how to delete and download new certificates. Sorry this was awhile ago so it’s a little hard to remember the details of it all.